# click a button based on div id and value with a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following situation. I need to simulate a button click on the off value button under a div based on its id

```
<div id="deviceControls1">
<button value="Off">Off</button>
<button value="On" class="active">On</button>
</div>

<div id="deviceControls2">
<button value="Off">Off</button>
<button value="On" class="active">On</button>
</div
```

I know this is not valid code but in other words id like:

```
 document.getElementById('deviceControls2').getElementsByValue('Off').click();
```

Im not sure how to use javascript to obtain this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript, try this:

```
var buttons = document.getElementById('deviceControls2').getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].value == 'Off') { 
        buttons[i].click();
    }
}
```

Using jQuery (since you have it tagged):

```
$('#deviceControls2').children('button[value="Off"]').click();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Im just curious is there really no cleaner way in JS

Comment: I think that's why jQuery is so popular

Comment: That's exactly what jQuery is doing, abstracting away a bit of the JavaScript... ;)

Comment: querySelectorAll() would make it cleaner

Comment: @mahdilamb Show me please

Comment: var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#deviceControls2 button[value="Off"]'); for(var i=0, bl = buttons.length; i < bl; i++){ buttons[i].onclick(); }

Answer (score 1):

You've included the jQuery tag, so if you are using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$('#deviceControls2 > button[value="Off"]').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find this link useful: [Creating and triggering events - Web developer guide | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

For instance, to simulate click on "Tags" link in stackoverflow, you can do

```
  var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    'view': window,
    'bubbles': true,
    'cancelable': true
  });
var navTags = document.getElementById('nav-tags'); 
var canceled = !navTags.dispatchEvent(event);
```

---

this post was edited and, below was my old answer using old APIs.

You can do something like:

```
var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
event.initEvent('click', true, true);
var element =  document.getElementById('deviceControls2').getElementsByValue('Off');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```